# Ionic 5 - how to modify ion-button expand="block" width

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have this line

```
<ion-button expand="block" id="create" shape="round">Create Account</ion-button>
```

I would like to increase the width of this button. 
I can't find any way to increase the button height and width.
I have tried to use an id. That didn't do anything.

```
#create {
    --width: 250px;
    --height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `--width` and `--heigth` are valid css properties, can you try using `width` and `height` whitout the `--`

Comment: I think I will go crazy. But yes that worked !! Post that as answer I will approve it !!

Comment: I'm glad I could help !

Comment: to define a background you use --background !! but then you could use normal css to modify other stuff. I have spent hours trying to figure this out lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using invalid css properties ( `--width`and `--heigth` ). I think you are looking for `height`  and `width`.

```
#create {
    width: 250px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to ionic, but you should try with `<ion-content> <ion-button></ion-button> </ion-content>`